# Scrollbar size wrong after filtering a forms record source

Tags: ms-access, vba

The forms recordsource is 1900 records & then gets filtered based on what user selects in a combobox list, in VBA I have a SELECT CASE statement to do something like the below for each selection

```
Private Sub cmbDateRange_AfterUpdate()
SELECT CASE Me.cmbDateRange.Value
    Case "Yesterday"
        Me.Filter = "messageDateandtime BETWEEN #" & Date - 1 & "# AND #" & Date - 1 & " 23:59#"
    Case "Past 7 Days"
        Me.Filter = "messageDateandtime BETWEEN #" & Date - 7 & "# AND #" & Date & " 23:59#"
End Select
Me.FilterOn = True
Me.Recordset.MoveLast: Me.Recordset.MoveFirst
```

The last line is a cheap hack that is working to fix the scroll bars being long for the original record set 1900, whereas this filter should be like 100. I am guessing there is a better/more-efficient way?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you alter the form's Record Source property instead of its Filter property?

Comment: Do you think the last line is the correct solution? I tried what you suggested, but just to make a liar out of me it seemed to work as is. However I realized this AFTER I tried your suggestion & then switched back. Was this correct: Me.RecordSource = Mid(Me.RecordSource, 1, InStr(1, Me.RecordSource, "WHERE") - 1) & "WHERE messageDateandtime BETWEEN #" & Date & "# AND #" & Date & " 23:59#"

Comment: I didn't pay much attention to the details of that code before because I was focused on only the scrollbar issue.  Looking closer, I'm puzzled about `Select Case` without even one `Case` before `End Select`.  I'm unsure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Is it ... the record source includes a field named `date` and you want the filter to display only rows where `date` is from today regardless of the time of day part contained in `date`?

Comment: My code was wrong, sorry. Yes it includes a date field, its actually called `messageDateandtime`. Yes I want to filter by time & that code is working. I feel like that cheap hack shouldn't be necessary & I'd like validation that is the correct way about 'fixing' it (the scroll bars being longer then they should for the data displayed on the form)

Comment: I created a test form to play with this.  Altering `Me.RecordSource` causes the size of the scroll bar slider to adjust sanely and immediately.  If you want to use `Me.Filter` instead of `Me.RecordSource` for this, I don't see a better way than `MoveLast;MoveFirst` to adjust the slider size.